# Dispatching several actions in sequence for single reducer doesn't reflect changes in state for connected component

Tags: redux, react-redux

When dispatching several different actions for one reducer, only the last one triggers component update. It might be better to [show](http://codesandbox.io/s/LLVGBnQA) then explain.

Some notes on provided example:

1. `App` component reflects a history of updates of it's prop `redirectPath`. When it comes as `null` then `no redirect` string adds to history.
2. There is a reducer which returns just a plain `string` or `null` depending on action.
3. By pressing a button `Do redirect` I expect both actions (`SET_REDIRECT` and `CLEAR_REDIRECT`) provide changed state to `AppContainer` component. But only the latest one (`CLEAR_REDIRECT`) triggers render method with `null` value.
4. If we add slight delay between dispatching these actions, then both of them trigger component's render. You can check it by pressing `Do redirect with delay` button.

I expect both changes (provided by `SET_REDIRECT` and `CLEAR_REDIRECT` actions) in state should trigger component update without using `setTimeout` when dispatching actions.

I also tried to move dispatching of `CLEAR_REDIRECT` from middleware, after it gets `SET_REDIRECT`, but the same result.

Can I somehow reach expected behaviour?

Initially I posted the issues to redux repo, because I thought it's an issue in redux, but @jimbolla explained me that it's mostly by design of react.

Here is the reference to the original issues and comments from redux team member https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/2532.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever rely on performing state updates in `render()`. The only code that should be executed in `render()` is the code required to construct the view.

You could use `componentWillReceiveProps` to track when your component receives new properties.

You should listen for the appropriate property and perform your redirect when received. You should then listened for a property that indicates the redirection was successful and then you can dispatch an action to clear the redirect state if required which will trigger another component update.

Comment: `You could use componentWillReceiveProps`

That's a very right point. I've came to it also.